# How to delete an auto py to exe executable file?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, tkinter, python-3.7, autopy

I have made a exe file with auto py to exe. But when I opened it I have some problems. So I decided to delete it. But when I am selecting the file and pressing SHIFT+DEL, then it would say it is open in another exe program. Can someone say a solution?[Click here please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CoNA.gif)

Comment: Try opening task manager, and closing all the task except the task manager itself. Then attempt the deletion.

Comment: Okay  Sir . i am going to try it

Comment: Thanks sir it worked. can you type your answer as a n answer here so that I can  mark it as Correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try opening `task manager`, and closing all the task except the task manager itself. Then attempt the deletion.

There are some background process of the python interpreter which keep running even after the app finishes executing.

I've observed this happening with some of the IDEs (like thonny) and editors as well who sometimes won't close out the connections to the files.

That's one of the reasons we have `try-finally` blocks in python.